# What's this part called? (a manual transmission shifting mechanism connecting to the shifter under the hood. 2000 hyundai accent)

Tags: manual-transmission, hyundai, part-identification, accent, shifter

[image]
Close up of it.

[image: Zoomed out picture of same part]
Zoomed out, to show it's relative location.

Awhile back, I was trying to see what I could do to improve the feel of the shifter, and decided to proactively replace the gear oil and lubricate whatever I could. Replacing the gear oil didn't affect this much (I'm a newb. I don't know), but I did end up spraying down the part in the first image with WD-40 and the shifter improved right away, but temporarily.

What is that part called?

(bonus question: Any thoughts how how to improve my shifter?)

Comment: What you've circled is the shift *linkage**s***. I highlight the "s", because there's several link connections going on here. Instead of using WD40, use something a little more substantial. Some regular engine oil, while being sloppy, should provide you some lubrication with some sticking power. If you are really venturous, you could take it apart and lube it with bearing grease.

Comment: Awesome! I like the adventurous option. Thanks for helping me identify it. Using the correct term in my google searches yields matching results now!